# active record error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an select query using active records and I am using codeigniter 2.1, I get the following error in my code

```
          `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 82
```

`

Here is my controller code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Carbonrates extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //Load Dependencies     

}

// List all your items
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('ratesmodel');

    $electricity_provider = $this->input->post('providerNo');

    $carbon_rate = $this->ratesmodel->carbon($electricity_provider);

    var_dump($carbon_rate);

    return false;
}
```

}

And my model

```
    `    function carbon($provider) {           

        $this->db->select($provider);
        $where = array('username' => $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['username']);

        if($provider == 1 ) {

            $this->db->select('Winter_Night_Time1'); 
            $this->db->from('carbon_rates');   
            $this->db->where('username', $where);
            return $this->db->get()->result();  


        }`
```

I have googled for possible answers but haven't found any yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $where is an array, try:

```
function carbon($provider) {           

        $this->db->select($provider);
        $where = array('username' => $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['username']);

        if($provider == 1 ) {

            $this->db->select('Winter_Night_Time1'); 
            $this->db->from('carbon_rates');   
            $this->db->where($where);
            return $this->db->get()->result();  


        }
```

i.e. take the 'username' param from your `where` call...

EDIT ***

Line 82 on DB_Active_rec.php is the select.  so check your first `select` call for $provider, and ensure this is either comma-separated string or array of table names... anything else will not work. i.e. `if ($provider == 1)` you will get this error trying to call `$this->db->select(1);`

TRY:

```
function carbon($provider) {           

    if($provider == 1 ) {

        $this->db->select('Winter_Night_Time1'); 
        $this->db->from('carbon_rates');   
        $this->db->where('username', $where);
        return $this->db->get()->result();  


    }

    $this->db->select($provider);
    $where = array('username' => $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['username']);
```

Comment: I actually found the mistake, The $where variable was an array which is not allowed.

Comment: thats what I wrote at the top... :)